# How can access to routerLink value via custom directive?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-routerlink

How can I create a custom directive(e.g. **appCheckPermission** ) to check if user can view a link or button base on routerLink that applied to that element.

`<button [routerLink]="['/users/edit', userId]" appCheckPermission ></button>`

p.s:
there is a property that save routerlink value

> nativeElement.attributes["ng-reflect-router-link"].value

but can not be access via custom directive.

Comment: nativeElement.attributes["ng-reflect-router-link"].value also accessible inside life cycle hooks and I can use it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be accessible as an `Input` property and inside the lifecycle hooks

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appCheckPermission]' })
export class AppCheckPermissionDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() routerLink: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.routerLink);
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. but It does not work check it [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1iqctm?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/check-permission.directive.ts)

Comment: @user3910994 you need to access it inside the init lifecycle hook, it might not be available in constructor. Updated the snippet for your reference accordingly.

Comment: thank you. it's work

Answer (score 0):

You can access the router link in the directive in `ngOnChanges` Lifecycle hook.

```js
import { Directive, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCheckPermission]',
})
export class CheckPermissionDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() routerLink: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes && changes.routerLink) {
      console.log(changes.routerLink.currentValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer